# Function space and interior

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B=\{ f\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})~~|~~ f(x)>0 ~~\rm{on ~ } \mathbb{R} \}$.
I know this set is not open because of the function $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}({\rm{cos}}x +2)$
     . However, I can't find the infimum of this set.

Comment: Moreover can you give an argument for the openness of $B$?

Comment: @Naive/ Ooops, there was a mistake. The cosine function is not an answer. We should consider the function generated by 1/x.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, where $f\equiv0$.

Comment: Is this an hint for interior?

Comment: Nope, for the infimum.